# Listbox Always Getting focus first

Tags: ms-access, listbox, controls, categories

This might be a useless question, but it is a troublesome one.

Is there anyone that knows if the list box control has a nasty habit of getting focus first (regardless of tab control). I have a tab control which contains a list box on one tab (say tab A for short, call the other tab tab B). On this list box, a message is set to fire on OnGotFocus , warning the user about a specific detail of the listbox (for data entry purposes). Also note that there are other controls on tab A, and the list box is at the END of the tab order.

Here is the issue:

When switching from tab A to B, and then back to A , the message fires for the list box, regardless of what control I was in on tab A prior to leaving tab A.

Is something causing the listbox to gain precedence that's overriding the tab order? Do I need to consider putting my macro on a different Event? Perhaps something else? I am considering adding something to the onclick event for the tab A page in question, but I figure this might end up firing every single time any part of the page is clicked. This isn't what I'm looking for. I'm also considering trying to "negate" the tab control entirely by creating my own set of buttons which could control the pages instead. Any thoughts on these alternative plans would be helpful too.

Note that it's best if I do this in macros. I am willing to consider VBA but I know very little.

I am not sure if I am explaining this well. I'm willing to respond with more details.

Comment: Do you really need to annoy users with a popup message they will have to just close every time they visit this listbox? Why not just put the info in a label with big red text?

Comment: I find that if listbox selected item has dotted line around it, listbox gets focus when returning to tab page, regardless of what control had focus when leaving. I can make the dotted line disappear temporarily with right click over listbox which opens shortcut menu then clicking away onto textbox. I seldom use listbox for data entry.

Comment: Change the focus of the current control to the first control in the tab page. You can use the `Change` event of the tab control. See a few samples of using the event here https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/tabs/index.html

Comment: The tab control is actually just grouping your controls visually. Logically they are all on the same form, in the object hierarchy. So you'll need to customize the function of the page changes to the visual expectation.

Comment: If the controls where just 'logically all on the same form', then TabOrder numbering should be continuous across all tab pages, but it is not. TabOrder numbering starts with 0 for each set of controls on each page. Yes, if you were to loop all controls on form, the loop would include all controls on all pages, however, something else is involved when navigating between pages as indicated by TabOrder numbering.

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance so far. @June7, I find that there is no "dotted line" in my form when selecting the list box. Perhaps I have a setting turned off for that? Regardless, doing the right click does not fix the problem. I am attempting to figure out a different way to do this. Do you guys know if there is a simple way to make a message box appear once at the opening of the form (with the same information) and then the user could choose to not display it again? If that makes sense

Comment: The wild thing about this is I have another form which has a very similar scenario. Except on that one, this scenario absolutely never happens. The situation is virtually the same and the macros are near identical. Why would one form act so differently?

Comment: A fairly simple solution to this. I was able to make a transparent button on top of the tab A in question. On the OnClick event for this button, I have written a macro that uses GoToControl to move the focus to the first important control in tab A. This "might" avoid the issue. This makes it seemingly impossible for the listbox to steal the focus without the user intentionally setting the focus on the listbox. The question still remains if a better option (i.e, not having the listbox all together) is needed. Ideally, I would like to have the msgbox appear but perhaps the user could opt out.

Comment: When I select an item in listbox, it shows a dotted line around that item as well as highlights it. Can certainly make a message box appear with code in form Load or Open event. Are listboxes bound? No idea why forms act different. I would have to examine.